# How to add approve booking requests in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Bookings resources. To approve the bookings, I added in my BookingsController the **approve** method:

```
def approve
@booking = Booking.find_by_id(params[:id])
 @booking.update(state: "approved")
 if @booking.state == "approved"
   flash[:success] = "Booking successfully approved"
   redirect_to bookings_path
 else
   flash[:error] = "Booking not approved"
   redirect_to bookings_path
 end
```

end

To approve a booking, I used the link:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Approve', bookings_approve(id: booking.id), class: "button-xs success" %></td>
```

I am not sure about the link to approve and the corresponding routes definition. How do I defined the routes and the link to aprrove ?

Each booking has a status field which I want to change to 'approved' when the Approve button is pressed . 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please post your `routes.rb` as well

Comment: This seems like it is a choice between adding a column to bookings (e.g. a boolean `bookings.approved`) or a new `approvals` table. Do you need to know who approved it and when? Can the approval have other information associated with it? If so a new `approvals` resource may save you work in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
resources :bookings do 
  member do
    post :approve
  end
end
```

Which will give you (on `rake routes`):

```
approve_booking POST   /bookings/:id/approve(.:format)         bookings#approve
       bookings GET    /bookings(.:format)                     bookings#index
                POST   /bookings(.:format)                     bookings#create
    new_booking GET    /bookings/new(.:format)                 bookings#new
   edit_booking GET    /bookings/:id/edit(.:format)            bookings#edit
        booking GET    /bookings/:id(.:format)                 bookings#show
                PATCH  /bookings/:id(.:format)                 bookings#update
                PUT    /bookings/:id(.:format)                 bookings#update
                DELETE /bookings/:id(.:format)                 bookings#destroy
```

And then do:

```
<td>
  <%= link_to 'Approve', approve_booking_path(booking), class: "button-xs success", method: :post %>
</td>
```

BTW, you say you have a `status` field, but in your controller method, you do:

```
@booking.update(state: "approved")
```

`state` != `status`...